# Did I just get scammed by CEX.io?

Tags: transactions

I bought some ETH off CEX.io upon the recommendation of a couple friends, and tried to transfer it to my wallet in Bitfinex. This transfer was done [around 24 hours ago](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x36ed078e0394ddbbcee0bb3964e13d69b77ef34dda82a78f59b3bb4b7251e72d) and yet the transaction hash does not exist. CEX on Twitter announced that it stopped all ETH transactions and blames it on some "error on the blockchain". Did I just get screwed?

Answer (score 1):

[kittens clogged](https://www.coindesk.com/loveable-digital-kittens-clogging-ethereums-blockchain/) the network recently.

Try resending your transaction with higher gas price. You can get an idea about the network status and required gas price from here:
https://ethgasstation.info/